# Stability analysis of ODEs containing non-linear terms

Tags: stability, non-linear-systems, complex-systems

[I am currently reading this lecture notes on non-linear dynamics.](https://www.ioc.ee/%7Edima/YFX1520/LectureNotes_4.pdf)  If you look at equation (7) it is easy to write the ODEs,
$\dot{x} = y$ and $\dot{y} = -x$ into a matrix form $\dot{\vec{x}}=A\vec{x}$.  If I have a complicated coupled ODEs, lets say
$\dot{x} = xy$ and $\dot{y}= -xy$, these equations contains bi-linear terms.  Is it possible to write these ODEs in matrix form $\dot{\vec{x}}=A\vec{x}$ for doing stability analysis? or is there any other way to do stability analysis for the kind of ODEs which contains bi-linear or tri-linear systems?

Comment: You can use the Jacobian to analyze the behavior of the system.

Comment: Any good resources/notes available on how to find Jacobian of a nonlinear system?

Comment: In Igor Yanovsky's solved problems in ODE there are a few examples.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure I'm addressing your general question, but your particular example, $\dot{x} = xy$ ; $\dot{y}= -xy$, is instantly convertible to  just one autonomous ODE, with evident stability properties, in light-cone coordinates,
$$
 x \equiv \frac{\xi+\eta}{2}, \qquad y\equiv \frac{\xi-\eta}{2},\\
\dot{\xi}=0, \qquad \dot{\eta}= -\tfrac{1}{2} (\eta-\xi)(\eta+\xi), 
$$
where the only variable is *η*, while *ξ* is just a constant. So you immediately assess the stability around the fixed points: for   *η* < -*ξ*,  or   -*ξ* < *η* < *ξ*   , or else *η* > *ξ*.

You might consider these statements plotted in your original *x,y* variables. In fact, dividing the original two coupled ODEs by each other, you see the linear trajectories in the *x,y*  plane, with a transparent stability profile.